# Kotlin layout id is showing two imports

Tags: android, kotlin

I imported a module to my project. That module was working in my sample,

But in my app this is showing two imports, Can someone let me know, why did this happen. And what will be its solution. Because I never imported the ids in kotlin, so why I faced this behaviour now?

[image]

**Please note:**

It is not about one id `drawer_layout`, all my ids are showing two imports, Also please note that I never imported all these ids in my old sample project. But in my other app, all ids are showing two imports.

**Edit**

I am adding some additional screenshots for better understanding.

#### No duplicate id

[image: No duplicate id]

#### But showing two imports

[image: Two imports]

#### All ids are showing two imports in class (Almost 100 erros in class)

[image: Errors]

Comment: do you use synthetic view binding? You need to tell what layout you are binding to. In this case it would be the 2nd option

Comment: @TimCastelijns , yes i am aware of it that synthetic import is the one I need, But I don't know why there are two imports, Because it was working in another app, same module is not working in another app.

Comment: there are 2 options because the module you imported provides a R.id.drawar_layout. AS does not know which one to import. You have to tell it.

Comment: @TimCastelijns in kotlin I never imported any id like this, I can see there are not any imports for synthetic also, it automatically takes reference.

Comment: @TimCastelijns please try to understand, I am not talking about single id, all my id (above 100) are showing two imports.

Comment: show an example of an view reference that is not `drawer_layout` that also shows 2 options

Comment: @TimCastelijns I have edited my question for better understanding

Comment: what happens when you import the synthetic layout?

Comment: 1. It is imported, 2. It does not add any imports in class, 3. All errors related to that id are gone.

Comment: make sure not to import single id, but import the whole layout

Comment: @TimCastelijns But here big question is why all ids are available at two places in another project, weather in one project I don't need to import any id.

Comment: @TimCastelijns please let me know how to import whole layout?

Answer (score 0):

it's automatic in kotlin. You just have to choose kotlinx.android.synthetic

I've tried it in fragments and it can't. when in fragment you still have to use findViewById

Comment: It works in fragments as well. You need to choose `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_main.*`

Answer (score 0):

So if you have a view in the xml layout with id = drawer_layout, there are two imports:

1. `acr.browser.lightning.R.id.drawer_layout` : This is the ID mapping that you will find in your `R.java` file. You will have an entry for every view there. This import exists even when you are not using kotlin. You will use this, for example, when you want to compare the View Id to determine which View is clicked, etc...
2. `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.drawer_layout` : Now this is the way by which you can access the VIEW without using `findViewById` and [reference it directly](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html).

Looking at your code, I see that the 2nd import is what you need to choose. It's normal for the IDE to show both the imports, because both are valid. Now, [there is a bug in Android Studio](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78547457) (at least in the 3.1 version), where even when you choose the 2nd import, sometimes Android Studio will show ALL THE ID's as errors (since it won't recognize the synthetic import). To resolve this you need to Build the app again, and the errors will go away (if the synthetic import is still present)